# Не могу задать тень

Tags: html5, css3

Нужна тень как на изображении, то есть только по бокам и в двух моментах снизу (ближе к футеру). Во всех генераторах теней, тень не смог настроить, чтоб была только снизу или сверху. Каким образом можно реализовать такую тень ? И если можно, напишите сразу box-shadow: .. .. ..

[image: Тень]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`box-shadow` - это прямоугольник тени за объектом.
Вы можете его двигать, масштабировать и размывать.
"Тень с двух боков" - это нечто некорректное.

Однако, всё же можно скомбинировать несколько теней:

```css
.card {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 
   -5px 0 3px -1px lightgreen,
    5px 0 3px -1px lightgreen
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel quam lacinia, lacinia est sit amet, mollis dolor. 
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я еще сделал по вашему первому комментарию, хотел отметить, но вы видимо стёрли его :)

Answer (score 3):

как вариант

```css
.card{overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:20px}
.card div{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel quam lacinia, lacinia est sit amet, mollis dolor.</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel quam lacinia, lacinia est sit amet, mollis dolor.</div>
</div>
```

первый естессно, кошернее. но у этого подцветов снизу/сверху нет.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуюсь этим: http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow
Очень удобная вещь
Если лень делать, то вот css для box-shadow внизу блока:
box-shadow:

`0px 5px 15px -5px rgba(64,64,64,0.7);`

Comment: Делать не лень, такая тень появляется снизу и с боков. Но ведь дело в том, что я не могу задать тень всему шаблону же (а может просто не умею или не знаю чего-то). Я задаю тень секциям и получается, что у секций тень с боков и + тень снизу, которая ненужна.